# Create a deeplink for destination wiht safe args

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-deep-link, android-safe-args

I created a deeplink for a destination but came to the wrong page.
Sure about defining navigation in the manifest and the other config.
For example:

```
<deepLink
        android:id="@+id/deeplink"
        app:uri="example://receipt/payment/?status={transactionStatus}&amp;trace_id={traceNumber}" />

<argument
        android:name="transactionStatus"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        app:argType="boolean" />

    <argument
        android:name="traceNumber"
        app:argType="string" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice: if you define arguments and they are not nullable you have to send arguments with deeplink.
So you have to change arguments to:

```
<argument
        android:name="transactionStatus"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        app:nullable="true"
        app:argType="boolean" />

    <argument
        android:name="traceNumber"
        app:nullable="true"
        app:argType="string" />
```